# How to update object properties with Func<>?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

> Is it somehow possible to update object properties by using
>   `Func` with lambda expression?

---

**Foo class**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id      { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age     { get; set; }
    //... many others
}
```

**Util class**

```
public static class Updater
{
    public Foo FooUpdate(Foo item, params Func<Foo, object> properties)
    {
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            //take value of property and set it on item object
        }
        return item
    } 
}
```

**Initial call**

```
   var updatedFoo = Updater.FooUpdate(item, p => p.Id = 10, p => p.Name = "Test", ...);
```

After `FooUpdate` method, I want to receive `updatedFoo` object, with given value parameters in given call. `Id = 10` and `Name = "Test"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Func<Foo, object>` signature is invalid. A lambda `p => p.Id = 10` does not return an `object`.
If you wanted to simply change the existing method to work then this would do:

```
 public Foo FooUpdate(Foo item, params Action<Foo> properties)
 {
     foreach(var property in properties)
     {
        property(item);
     }
     return item
 }
```

But please note that this is a pretty bad design. First of all, your method both modifies the passed `item` and returns it - it should either modify it (and return `void`) or leave `item` as it was, clone it and then modify and return the clone. Second of all, I see no value at all in this `Util` method. Any call to it would be equivalent to just applying the updates line by line.

```
var updatedFoo = Updater.FooUpdate(item, p => p.Id = 10, p => p.Name = "Test", ...);
```

is the same as

```
item.Id = 10;
item.Name = "Test";
/* ... */
```

Comment: I don't know if the design is THAT bad, it follows pretty closely with the ASP.NET Core 2 configuration design.

Comment: @V0ldek I do note that it´s quite same, like setting properties line by line. I was curious if it is possible. I was not able to figure out how to do it. I gave you abbreviation of this example. There is no Util class in real example and after all, updated object is saved to database, so no cloning.

Comment: Then if you just want to modify the object, make the method return `void`.  It will be more transparent this way.

Comment: @saarrrr Could you elaborate? Afaik `Configuration` and `ConfigurationBuilder` follow the Builder pattern, an that's quite different from just an updating method.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Func` here because you don't need to return anything. You can just modify the foo by using an `Action`:

```
public Foo FooUpdate(Foo item, params Action<Foo>[] propertySetters)
{
       foreach(var propertySetter in propertySetters)
       {
            propertySetter(item);
       }

       return item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small method that allows updating value of an object by selecting a property.

Usage: `var result = UpdateByField(company, 1, x => x.Id);`

```
private T UpdateByField<T, TValue>(T obj, TValue value, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> selector)
{
    var memberExpression = selector.Body as MemberExpression;

    var field = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
    var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;

    if (field != default)
        field.SetValue(obj, value);

    if (property != default)
        property.SetValue(obj, value);

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: this solution is underrated. :)